# Show pie chart or progress bar for a testset

Tags: rally, appsdk2

I would like to be able to show status of execution of a testset by iteration and release and to show a progress bar (similar to that in the quality testplan page) or a pie chart (similar to those in iteration dashboard app) of the results so far for the testcases within the testset. Is there something already that exists to do this? any help is appreciated.

I found a post where the answer provided some code to show testsets and one sentence status instead of real breakdown of results here:
[Creating Reports for Test Cases per Iteration in Rally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18468633/creating-reports-for-test-cases-per-iteration-in-rally/18468824#18468824)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a js file of an app that builds a pie chart of testcaseresults filtered by itertation and further filtered by a testset. Testset dropdown is populated with testsets that are scheduled for iteration selected in the iteration dropdown.  Full app is available in [this repo](https://github.com/nmusaelian-rally/pie-with-test-set-picker).  You may customize it further to meet your specific requirements, e.g. add a release dropdown. Note that releases do not own iterations, and there is only an implicit association between them based on start and end dates. If you want to precede the selection in iteration dropdown by a selection in a release dropdown you may see code in [this repo](https://github.com/nmusaelian-rally/iterations-within-release),which queries for iterations that fall within a release.

```
Ext.define('CustomApp', {
    extend: 'Rally.app.TimeboxScopedApp',
    componentCls: 'app',
    scopeType: 'iteration',
    comboboxConfig: {
        fieldLabel: 'Select an Iteration:',
        labelWidth: 100,
        width: 300
    },

    onScopeChange: function() {
       if (this.down('#testSetComboxBox')) {
        this.down('#testSetComboxBox').destroy();   
    }
     if (this.down('#myChart')) {
        this.down('#myChart').destroy();
     }
    var testSetComboxBox = Ext.create('Rally.ui.combobox.ComboBox',{
        id: 'testSetComboxBox',
        storeConfig: {
        model: 'TestSet',
        limit: Infinity,
        pageSize: 100,
        autoLoad: true,
        filters: [this.getContext().getTimeboxScope().getQueryFilter()]
        },
        fieldLabel: 'select TestSet',
        listeners:{
                ready: function(combobox){
            if (combobox.getRecord()) {
            this._onTestSetSelected(combobox.getRecord());
            }
            else{
            console.log('selected iteration has no testsets');
            if (this.down('#grid')) {
                this.down('#grid').destroy();
            }
            }
        },
                select: function(combobox){
            if (combobox.getRecord()) {
              if (this.down('#myChart')) {
              this.down('#myChart').destroy();
              this._onTestSetSelected(combobox.getRecord());
              }

            }           
                },
                scope: this
            }
    });
    this.add(testSetComboxBox);  
    },

     _onTestSetSelected:function(testset){
      this._myMask = new Ext.LoadMask(Ext.getBody(), {msg:"Please wait.This may take long if you have thousands of results..."});
      this._myMask.show();
    this._myStore = Ext.create('Rally.data.WsapiDataStore', {
           model: 'Test Case Result',
       limit: Infinity,
           fetch: ['Verdict','TestCase','Build'],
       filters:[
        {
          property: 'TestSet',
          value: testset.get('_ref')
        }
       ],
           autoLoad: true,
           listeners: {
              load: this._onDataLoaded,
              scope: this
            }
       });
     },


     _onDataLoaded: function(store, data) {
          this._myMask.hide();
      var records = [];
      var verdictsGroups = ["Pass","Blocked","Error","Fail","Inconclusive"]

      var passCount = 0;
      var blockedCount = 0;
      var errorCount = 0;
      var failCount = 0;
      var inconclusiveCount = 0;

      var getColor = {
          'Pass': '#009900',
          'Blocked': '#FF8000',
          'Error': '#990000', 
          'Fail': '#FF0000', 
          'Inconclusive': '#A0A0A0'
      };

      Ext.Array.each(data, function(record) {
          verdict = record.get('Verdict');
          switch(verdict)
          {
          case "Pass":
             passCount++;
              break;
          case "Blocked":
              blockedCount++;
              break;
          case "Error":
              errorCount++;
              break;
          case "Fail":
              failCount++;
              break;
          case "Inconclusive":
              inconclusiveCount++;
          }
      });
      if (this.down('#myChart')) {
              this.remove('myChart');
      }
      if (this.down('#myChart2')) {
              this.remove('myChart2');
      }
      this.add(
          {
            xtype: 'rallychart',
            height: 400,
            storeType: 'Rally.data.WsapiDataStore',
            store: this._myStore,
            itemId: 'myChart',
            chartConfig: {
                chart: {
                type: 'pie'
                },
                title: {
                text: 'TestCaseResults Verdict Counts',
                align: 'center'
                },
                tooltip: {
                formatter: function () {
                   return this.point.name + ': <b>' + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.percentage, 1) + '%</b><br />' + this.point.y;
                    }
                },
                plotOptions : {
                 pie: {
                    allowPointSelect: true,
                    cursor: 'pointer',
                    point: {
                    events: {
                        click: function(event) {
                        var options = this.options;
                        alert(options.name + ' clicked');
                        }
                    }
                    },
                    dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    color: '#000000',
                    connectorColor: '#000000'
                    }
                }
                }
            },            
            chartData: {
                series: [ 
                {   
                    name: 'Verdicts',
                    data: [
                    {name: 'Pass',
                    y: passCount,
                    color: getColor['Pass']
                    },
                    {name: 'Blocked',
                    y: blockedCount,
                    color: getColor['Blocked']
                    },
                    {name: 'Fail',
                    y: failCount,
                    color: getColor['Fail']
                    },
                    {name: 'Error',
                     y: errorCount,
                    color: getColor['Error']
                    },
                    {name: 'Inconclusive',
                     y: inconclusiveCount,
                    color: getColor['Inconclusive']
                    }
                      ]
                }
                ]
            }
        }
    );
    this.down('#myChart')._unmask();
    }

 });
```